# Style added by Javascript doesn't work in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I'm using https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat to scroll through a list of items. There seems to be a bug in the IOS browsers where you scroll the repeat content through an overlay element.

When I add `-WebKit-transform: translateZ(0px);` to `.md-virtual-repeat-scroller` I can completely disable the scrolling of the repeat content. So I want to add this style when the overlay is active. (the overlay, in this case, is a search bar with some results. Scrolling through the results also scrolls the repeat content underneath it).

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
    overflow-y: visible;
    &.no-scroll {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
        color: red!important;
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
const infiniteScrollers = document.querySelectorAll('.md-virtual-repeat-scroller');
Array.from(infiniteScrollers).forEach(element => {
    element.classList.add('no-scroll');
});
```

When I run this code the text turns to red when the overlay is active but I can still scroll through the repeat content.

If I manually add the style:

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
    overflow-y: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    &.no-scroll {
        color: red !important;
    }
}
```

Why is this `-WebKit-transform: translateZ(0px);` not working when it's added through Javascript, but it does work when I directly implement it in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but overriding the `overflow-y: visible;` with in the:

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
    overflow-y: visible;
    &.no-scroll {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    }
 }
```

In the `.no-scroll`:

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
    overflow-y: visible;
    &.no-scroll {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
 }
```

Fixes the issue. I don't know why adding the transform directly works, but I have to override the `overflow-y` when added the css through Javascript. I'm going to leave the question, maybe someone runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the browser compatibility to support for all browsers.

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
   overflow-y: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  &.no-scroll {
    color: red !important;
  }
 }
```